# JSON to Java mapping of inner object?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I've the below class:

```
public class PersonResponse {
    public static final class Profile {
        int id;
    }
    public static class Error {
        String message;
        int code;
    }
    String name;
    Profile profile;
    //getters/setters
}
```

to map *JSON* response such as following:

```
{
    "name" : "first last",
    "profile" : {
        "id" : 1234
    },
    "error" : {
        "message": "some random error",
        "code" : 404
    }
}
```

This works fine but I've one endpoint that returns just the `Profile` object or some error. Therefore the response could be:

```
 {
    "id" : 1234
 }
```

OR

```
{
  "message": "profile not found",
  "code" : 404
}
```

Is there any way to reuse the `PersonResponse` class in this case rather than adding an error object inside the `Profile` object too ?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot ?

Comment: @EduardoEljaiek yes

Comment: I'm posting a solution using @JsonViews

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, It's possible you can do it using *Jackson* `@JsonView`.

First you must create a class for declaring your views.

```java
    public class PersonResponseViews {

        public static class Person { }

        public static class Profile { }
    }
```

Then you must include these changes in `PersonResponse` class

```java
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;

    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
    class PersonResponse {

        @JsonView(PersonResponseViews.Person.class)
        String name;

        @JsonView(PersonResponseViews.Person.class)
        Profile profile;

        @JsonView({
            PersonResponseViews.Person.class,
            PersonResponseViews.Profile.class
        })
        Error error;

        @JsonProperty("id")
        @JsonView(PersonResponseViews.Profile.class)
        int getProfileId() {
            int id = 0;

            if (profile != null) {
                id = profile.id;
            }

            return id;
        }

        @JsonView({
            PersonResponseViews.Person.class,
            PersonResponseViews.Profile.class
        })
        @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
        static class Error {

            String message;
            int code;
        }

        @JsonView(PersonResponseViews.Person.class)
        @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
        static class Profile {
            int id;
        }
    }
```

How to use your *JSON* views with a *Spring Rest Controller*

```java
    @JsonView(PersonResponseViews.Person.class)
    @RequestMapping("/person")
    public @ResponseBody
    PersonResponse getPerson() {
        PersonResponse resp = new PersonResponse();  
        resp.name = "first last";
        resp.profile = new PersonResponse.Profile();
        resp.profile.id = 1234;
        resp.error = new PersonResponse.Error();
        resp.error.code = 404;
        resp.error.message = "some random error";
        return resp;
    }

    @JsonView(PersonResponseViews.Profile.class)
    @RequestMapping("/profile")
    public @ResponseBody
    PersonResponse getProfile() {
        PersonResponse resp = new PersonResponse();
        resp.profile = new PersonResponse.Profile();
        resp.profile.id = 1234;
        resp.error = new PersonResponse.Error();
        resp.error.code = 404;
        resp.error.message = "some random error";
        return resp;
    }
```

[image: It works]

Comment: If this is useful to you, please, remember to [up-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it and maybe [marking it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).